# Select TableRow and SelectionColor should be visible and then go off automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

What I was trying - I have a `UITableView`. On selecting any particular row it should show a selectionColor(Blue etc) and then it should disappear. Any property/code to do this? I am actually applying in in MyCalender view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer the delegates and datasource in tableview for this

The datasource sets the inputs to table

The delegate gives you callbacks of actions on the tableview .

So write the delegate methods ,include it in classdef UITableViewDelegate,connect it in xib

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This delegate method is invoked if you click on a particular row.The particular row is the row at the "indexpath"
finally include this line  which deselect the code

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

in your - `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UITableView and want to remove selection of the UITableViewCell. Then you have to use the below code to deselect tableview cell.

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

`

```
UIView *violetColor = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        //violetColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.824 green:0.749    blue:0.553 alpha:0.70];
        violetColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.724 green:0.749    blue:0.953 alpha:0.70];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = violetColor;
```

`

and then add this to your didselect `

```
if (indexPath != nil) {
        [mTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
`.i hope this will do the trick.
```

Answer (score 1):

In delegate method didSelectRowAtndexPath use this code

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```